# Laravel maatwebsite/excel (PhpSpreadsheet) and TCPDF wrong sheet orientation

Tags: laravel, pdf, tcpdf, phpspreadsheet, maatwebsite-excel

I have a Laravel application using the `maatwebsite/excel` package to generate and excel file. I also allow the user to download that excel file as a PDF.
The problem is that when the pdf is generated, the pagination is vertical and the content gets cut.

[image]

I have the excel file set to landscape but the pagination is still vertical. I can not find in the docs a way to set the pdf direction

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {

                // Landscope orientation
                $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }
        ];
}
```

I'm exporting the PDF file using the TCPDF library. I've seen a parameter in the docs to set as landscape but I can not figure out the way to pass the parameter to the TCPDF constructor with the maatwebsite/excel api. This is the syntax:

```
return (new GanttExport)->download('gantt_' . time() . '.pdf', Excel::TCPDF);
```

Comment: Have you found anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **BeforeSheet** event? It does work in my code. And dont forget to implement **Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents** interface within the class.

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return  [
        BeforeSheet::class => function (BeforeSheet $event) {
            $event->sheet
                ->getPageSetup()
                ->setOrientation(PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, is very similar to the other answer, just in case is helpful for someone

```
 AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {);
            $event->sheet
                ->getPageSetup()
                ->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  }
```

I had to write this in afterSheet because in beforeSheet didn't work for me. And I added this code too for A4 pages:

```
$event->sheet
                ->getPageSetup()
                ->setPaperSize(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
```